# XSLT transformation to the attibute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following question regarding XSLT transform - I need to transform the XML file considering the attribute values in all parent nodes up to the root. So having a code like this (consider XY attribute as a string with "X, Y" values):

```xml
<Layout XY="40,20">
   <Layout XY="0,20">
     <Circle OffsetX="0"/>
    </Layout>
   <Circle OffsetX="6" />
   <Layout XY="100,20">
    <Circle OffsetX="0"/>
    <Layout XY="200,20">
      <Circle OffsetX="5"/>
    </Layout>
   </Layout>
</Layout>
```

I need an output

```xml
<Layout XY="40,20">
   <Layout XY="0,20">
     <Circle OffsetX="40"/>
    </Layout>
   <Circle OffsetX="46" />
   <Layout XY="100,20">
    <Circle OffsetX="140"/>
    <Layout XY="200,20">
      <Circle OffsetX="345"/>
    </Layout>
   </Layout>
</Layout>
```

I was trying to use an XSLT transform using template like this:

```xml
<!-- Copy template -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Change values -->

<xsl:template match="Circle/@OffsetX">   
  <xsl:param name="newOffsetX" select="substring-before(../../@XY,',')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>       
    <xsl:attribute name="OffsetX">
      <xsl:value-of select=".+$newOffsetX"/>
    </xsl:attribute>               
</xsl:template>
```

but this is a solution only for one level up. Is it possible at all to do such a transformation only with the use of XSLT?

Comment: "*but this is a solution only for one level up*" Actually, that doesn't work at all. The parent of the `OffsetX` attribute is the Circle element itself, so the expression `../@XY` selects nothing and the result of the addition is `NaN`.

Comment: oh yes, sorry - it should be "substring-before(../../@XY,',')" I've omitted the selection of the grandparent of this attribute - not on prupose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with XSLT 1.0, you need a template that recursively traverses up the node tree:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@XY" mode="sumXOffset" name="SumXOffset">
    <xsl:param name="currentValue"
               select="substring-before(., ',')" />

    <xsl:variable name="sum">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="(../ancestor::*/@XY)[last()]" mode="sumXOffset" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue + 
                          concat('0', $sum)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@OffsetX">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:call-template name="SumXOffset">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentValue" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample XML, the result is:

```
<Layout XY="40,20">
  <Layout XY="0,20">
    <Circle OffsetX="40" />
  </Layout>
  <Circle OffsetX="46" />
  <Layout XY="100,20">
    <Circle OffsetX="140" />
    <Layout XY="200,20">
      <Circle OffsetX="345" />
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
</Layout>
```

If you have an XSLT 2.0 processor available, the solution is a lot simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@OffsetX">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select=". + sum(ancestor::*/@XY/substring-before(','))"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Circle/@OffsetX">  
    <xsl:variable name="previous-X">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*[@XY]">
            <x><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@XY, ',')"/></x>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="OffsetX">
        <xsl:value-of select=". + sum(exsl:node-set($previous-X)/x)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>               
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice Exsl:node set or variable method (xslt2), +1.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this in XSLT 1.0 without a recursive template (not that there is anything wrong with that!) and that is to pass the running total from template to template as a parameter. Essentially, use the `newOffsetX` parameter in the identity template too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:param name="newOffsetX" select="0" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="newOffsetX" select="$newOffsetX + number(substring-before(concat('0', @XY, ','), ','))" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@OffsetX">
        <xsl:param name="newOffsetX" select="0" />
        <xsl:attribute name="OffsetX">
            <xsl:value-of select="$newOffsetX + number(.)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The funny expression `substring-before(concat('0', @XY, ','), ',')` is to cope with nodes with no `@XY` attribute. When an `@XY` attribute is present, with a value of "40,20" for example, the 'concat' returns "040,20,", and so the X number is still numerically the same. When the `@XY` is not present, the `concat` returns `0,` and so the X number is "0".